# how to redirect my own login to admin login in django

Tags: django, authentication, admin

I created my own login template(the one suggested by Django documentation) which forwards to a view called `hola` (the main page), this one uses `hola.html` template. What I pretend is to forward admin users to the admin application's main page and non-admin users to `hola.py/hola.html`.

this is my hola view

```
def hola(request):
    if request.user.is_admin:
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/admin/')
    else:
        return render(request,'hola.html',{'usuario':request.user})
```

Comment: Are you using  your custom admin panel or django's admin pane?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In your `hola` view, check if the user is an admin (you can use [`User.is_staff`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User.is_staff) or [`User.is_superuser`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User.is_superuser)). If so, redirect them to the admin main page:

```
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse

...
return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('admin:index'))
```

Comment: can't it be  request.user.is_staff? the ckecking part

Comment: Yes, `request.user` is a `User` instance, so it has the `is_staff` and `is_superuser` properties.

Answer (score 2):

In additionto Sebastian's answer For Django 2.0 and above

```
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
```

is changed to

```
from django.urls import reverse
```